Design a mapping to display the average salary amount of all the employees against each employee record using IICS? How do we do this?
Expected Output:
EMP_ID | EMP_NAME   | SALARY | AVG_SALARY
101    | Michael    | 1800   | 1800
102    | Ronald     | 1800   | 1500
103    | Christoph  | 2000   | 1800
104    | Jennifer   | 2500   | 2000
105    | John       | 1800   | 1500

The aggregator function in IICS/power center returns only one value. How can we use aggregator transfomation in combination with any other transformation to achieve this?


Your Average in the given example seems incorrect
Use a Joiner to join the aggregated value to the dataset

